# Self-referencing in C Structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This part of K&R (The C book) got me thinking:

From the book:

```
struct tnode {
             char *word;
             int    count;
             struct tnode *left;
             struct tnode *right;
};
```

*The recursion declaration of a node might look chancy, but it's correct.*

Because tnode's defiition doesn't use a tnode, but merely a pointer to a tnode somehow the compiler gives us a free pass. But I'm wondering how the computer knows how much memory to give a tnode, when it is declared?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pointers have a fixed size (32/64 bit depending on the platform) so the compiler knows how much memory is need for the left and right pointers and can calculate the whole size of the struct.

For the same reason if you need a pointer it's enough to do a forward declaration `struct tnode;` and you can use a pointer for that struct, eg: `struct tree { struct tnode* root; };`

Comment: Technically, pointers to different types are allowed to have different sizes, so long as `sizeof(void *) >= sizeof(T *)` for all object types `T`.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: ...and, importantly in this case, all pointers to `struct` types have the same size and alignment requirements.

Comment: @Chris: technically, it's not *guaranteed* that `sizeof(void*) >= sizeof(T*)`. A deliberately perverse implementation could put an unused padding byte into non-void pointers, or more realistically consider a 16/16 segmented architecture which only actually has 24 bits of addressable space. Then legally a `void*` could be "compressed" into 3 bytes, while a `char*` is a full 4-byte far pointer (convenient to dereference). Whether implementers would bother is another matter, the point is just that many strange things are allowed, what's guaranteed is that a `void*` can hold any object's address.

Comment: @Steve - Actually, I think `char *` and `void *` are required to have the same representation under the standard. 6.2.5¶26 "A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type."

Comment: @Chris: oops. `int*`, then ;-) It would be particularly odd for a `char*` to be in a format that's inconvenient to dereference, though. I entirely agree with your prediction that `sizeof(void*) >= sizeof(T*)`, but it is AFAIK common sense rather than a guarantee of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you have 4 members in the `struct` each with known amount of memory requirements.

Though, `left` and `right` are pointers of type `tnode`, memory allocation for their members isn't needed until an instance of `tnode` created using `malloc()` and the address of the instance assigned to them.